# Installing linux-firmware from 17.10 on 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, 17.04, firmware

I am having trouble getting firmware to load on on a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (dell xps 13).

It looks like the most recent firmware updates have not made it into 17.04 yet, but they are available in 17.10 - are there any risks to manually updating the linux-firmare package to the later version?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from risk, there is doubt that the linux-firmware package from 17.10 will be useful. Here is the list of files relative to your device from linux-firmware in 17.04 Zesty:

```
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/notice_ath10k_firmware-5.txt
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/notice_ath10k_firmware-4.txt
```

And here is the list of files relative to your device in 17.10 Artful:

```
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/notice_ath10k_firmware-5.txt
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/notice_ath10k_firmware-4.txt
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/notice_ath10k_firmware-6.txt
```

As you can see, the only addition is */lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin* and its associated copyright and patent notice.

While it is tempting to add it to your firmware library, it is doubtful that the driver in 17.04 will load and use it. Please see:

```
modinfo ath10k_pci

filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
<snip>
```

As you can see, the driver in 17.04 will load and use firmware-4.bin or firmware-5.bin but not firmware-6.bin. To use the latest firmware, you probably also need the newer, possibly unstable, driver from 17.10.

Comment: Why do you call it "unstable, driver from 17.10"? The driver is in the kernel. That looks to be the same. Anyway kernels are stable.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 includes the linux kernel with Ubuntu customizations. Until 17.10 is actually released, I assume there may be a remaining issue or two.

Comment: If you look at these "customizations", you'll see that it is quite safe. )) It is mostly build configs.